# Postgres : prevent altering join condition in plan

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a modified query from JOB benchmark:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   company_type AS ct, 
       info_type AS it, 
       movie_companies AS mc, 
       movie_info_idx AS mi_idx, 
       title AS t 
WHERE  ct.ct_kind = 'production companies' 
AND    it.it_info = 'top 250 rank' 
AND    t.t_production_year >2010 
AND    ct.ct_id = mc.mc_company_type_id 
AND    t.t_id = mc.mc_movie_id 
AND    t.t_id = mi_idx.mii_movie_id 
AND    it.it_id = mi_idx.mii_info_type_id;
```

Now optimizer is introducing condition

```
mc.mc_movie_id = mi_idx.mii_movie_id
```

in plan.

Here is the plan

```
Hash Join  (cost=127405.50..221937.06 rows=150 width=275)
    Hash Cond: (t.t_id = mc.mc_movie_id)
    ->  Seq Scan on title t  (cost=0.00..91054.20 rows=926896 width=94)
            Filter: (t_production_year > 2010)
    ->  Hash  (cost=127398.60..127398.60 rows=552 width=181)
            ->  Hash Join  (cost=37908.32..127398.60 rows=552 width=181)
                    Hash Cond: (mc.mc_movie_id = mi_idx.mii_movie_id)  // HERE
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=18.93..89399.66 rows=20806 width=114)
                            Hash Cond: (mc.mc_company_type_id = ct.ct_id)
                            ->  Seq Scan on movie_companies mc  (cost=0.00..75323.67 rows=3693067 width=28)
                            ->  Hash  (cost=18.88..18.88 rows=4 width=86)
                                    ->  Seq Scan on company_type ct  (cost=0.00..18.88 rows=4 width=86)
                                            Filter: ((ct_kind)::text = 'production companies'::text)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=37676.66..37676.66 rows=17019 width=67)
                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.43..37676.66 rows=17019 width=67)
                                    Hash Cond: (mi_idx.mii_info_type_id = it.it_id)
                                    ->  Seq Scan on movie_info_idx mi_idx  (cost=0.00..30292.03 rows=1923203 width=49)
                                    ->  Hash  (cost=2.41..2.41 rows=1 width=18)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on info_type it  (cost=0.00..2.41 rows=1 width=18)
                                                    Filter: ((it_info)::text = 'top 250 rank'::text)
```

This condition

```
Hash Cond: (mc.mc_movie_id = mi_idx.mii_movie_id)
```

is not present in original sql query.

My question is, how can I prevent postgres from introducing this condition in plan?

The application is written in our lab as a proof of concept which assumes that there are only pk-fk joins in the database that's why I need it this way. The input to the application is the query plan.

I know it's better this way but I'm testing an application which only supports pk-fk joins. None of `mc_movie_id` or `mii_movie_id` is a pk.

Note: Using explicit `JOIN` syntax is not helping - the same plan is obtained.

Comment: Could you rewrite the query with **just** the PK and (relevant) FK fields? And also, include a pg_dump with the table structures! Finally, you could also maybe do a pastebin of the entire tables and/or post them to the internet as a file somewhere - since this is an academic project, I assume that the data is not sensitive?

Comment: @Vérace Sorry but I'm very busy atm, so I'll update extra information some time later. For now I'll use the workaround as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workarounds by changing the query

1. By changing one part to be a sub query and using *OFFSET 0*

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   company_type AS ct,
          movie_companies AS mc, (
              SELECT t_id 
              FROM   info_type AS it, 
                     movie_info_idx AS mi_idx, 
                     title AS t 
              WHERE  it.it_info = 'top 250 rank' 
              AND    t.t_id = mi_idx.mii_movie_id 
              AND    it.it_id = mi_idx.mii_info_type_id 
              AND    t.t_production_year >2010 OFFSET 0
              ) AS var 
   WHERE  var.t_id = mc.mc_movie_id 
   AND    ct.ct_kind = 'production companies' 
   AND    ct.ct_id = mc.mc_company_type_id;
   ```

   *OFFSET 0* won't allow optimizer to pull subquery up in plan tree.
2. One more workaround is to change query such that joins in query are in 
   order which we want and setting **join_collapse_limit = 1** in PostgreSQL 
   configuration file which essentially tells optimizer not to change join 
   order. [More about join_collapse_limit here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-FROM-COLLAPSE-LIMIT)
   Note : Explicit JOIN syntax should be used

   So new query with explicit join order will look like this

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   title AS t
   JOIN   movie_info_idx AS mi_idx ON t.t_id = mi_idx.mii_movie_id
   JOIN   info_type AS it ON it.it_id = mi_idx.mii_info_type_id
   JOIN   movie_companies AS mc ON t.t_id = mc.mc_movie_id
   JOIN   company_type AS ct ON ct.ct_id = mc.mc_company_type_id
   WHERE  ct.ct_kind = 'production companies'
   AND    it.it_info = 'top 250 rank'
   AND    mc.mc_note NOT LIKE '%(as Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer Pictures)%'
   AND    (
        mc.mc_note LIKE '%(co-production)%' 
     OR mc.mc_note LIKE '%(presents)%');
   ```

   Corresponding plan

   ```
   Hash Join  (cost=331522.33..438739.98 rows=1 width=281)
     Hash Cond: (mc.mc_company_type_id = ct.ct_id)
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=331503.40..438720.17 rows=234 width=195)
           Hash Cond: (mc.mc_movie_id = t.t_id)
           ->  Seq Scan on movie_companies mc  (cost=0.00..107038.63 rows=46879 width=34)
                 Filter: ((mc_note !~~ '%(as Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer Pictures)%'::text) AND ((mc_note ~~ '%(co-production)%'::text) OR (mc_note ~~ '%(presents)%'::text)))
           ->  Hash  (cost=331290.67..331290.67 rows=17019 width=161)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=174945.39..331290.67 rows=17019 width=161)
                       Hash Cond: (mi_idx.mii_info_type_id = it.it_id)
                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=174942.96..323906.04 rows=1923203 width=143)
                             Hash Cond: (mi_idx.mii_movie_id = t.t_id)
                             ->  Seq Scan on movie_info_idx mi_idx  (cost=0.00..30292.03 rows=1923203 width=49)
                             ->  Hash  (cost=82545.76..82545.76 rows=3403376 width=94)
                                   ->  Seq Scan on title t  (cost=0.00..82545.76 rows=3403376 width=94)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=2.41..2.41 rows=1 width=18)
                             ->  Seq Scan on info_type it  (cost=0.00..2.41 rows=1 width=18)
                                   Filter: ((it_info)::text = 'top 250 rank'::text)
     ->  Hash  (cost=18.88..18.88 rows=4 width=86)
           ->  Seq Scan on company_type ct  (cost=0.00..18.88 rows=4 width=86)
                 Filter: ((ct_kind)::text = 'production companies'::text)
   ```